# DateTime Conversion fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

My date string is like this

```
19-03-2014
```

And I want to convert it to

```
03/19/2014
```

Tried something like this

```
var bday = DateTime.ParseExact("19-03-2014", "dd/mm/yyyy",
         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

But this throws an error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Can any one point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just have a look at [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple issues in parsing.

- Your string has separator as `-` but you are using `/` in format.
- You are using lower case `mm` for month, it should be `MM`. Lower case `mm` is for minutes.

You can use single `d` and `M` for single/double digits day/month part. It would be a safer approach since it would recognize `03` or `3` as month. So your format should be:`"d-M-yyyy"`

and your parsing code can be:

```
var bday = DateTime.ParseExact("19-03-2014", 
                               "d-M-yyyy",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You should see: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings -MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

That is just because `mm` is minutes while `MM` is month

Comment: You should also mentioned the difference between date string and format.

Answer (score 2):

```
var bday = DateTime.ParseExact("19-03-2014", "dd-MM-yyyy",
                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(bday.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Comment: If OP's current culture date time seperator is not `/`, your `bday.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` represents his current culture's `DateTimeSeperator`. You can escape it like `bday.ToString("MM\/dd\/yyyy")`

Answer (score 1):

Your format is using `/` as the separator, but your date string has `-` as the separator.  Change it to

```
var bday = DateTime.ParseExact("19-03-2014", "dd-MM-yyyy",
                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: If OP's current culture date time seperator is not `/`, your code represents his current culture's `DateTimeSeperator`.

Answer (score 1):

You should parse it using the original format, then print it again in your desired format:

```
var bday = DateTime.ParseExact("19-03-2014", "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string s = bday.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```